# Use of medical words

Tags: capitalization, medical

When charting on a patient, and a choice is *high cholesterol*, should both be capitalized?

Comment: When the expression is used to designate a 'state', 'condition', 'factor' or other such designator, it is initial-capitalized: "Patient's parameters checked. Observations recorded: High Cholesterol"; "Possible etiology: High Cholesterol"; etc. Also note that within a sentence, it may or may not be capitalized, but in standalone mention, it is always capitalized.

Answer (score 3):

Neither word is a proper noun, so technically neither should be capitalized. If you want to capitalize them in "title case" (where terms exist outside of normal syntax and actually form a kind of title), go right ahead and capitalize whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

If I were filling in a chart, I would certainly capitalize both words, as in *"High Cholesterol"*. In any charting situation, clarity is the chief goal and capitalized words tend to be more easily read or referenced in cramped spaces -- crucial for important words.

Of course, *high* and *cholesterol* are not proper nouns and so should not be capitalized within a sentence. Thus, capitalizing them here would certainly be a matter of style. Since you are probably in a medical environment, I would suggest taking a peek at other colleagues' charts to see what the preferred style is. [Here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/8/29/figure/F1?highres=y) is a sample I found.